# My USB Thumb Drive is not mounting automatically on 15.10

Tags: usb, mount

Since I upgraded to 15.10 my thumb drives are not auto mounting when I insert my stick. There's nothing in dmesg. Here are the logs from syslog:

```
Dec 30 07:28:55 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174764.056053] usb 8-1.8: new 
full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
Dec 30 07:28:55 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174764.128031] usb 8-1.8: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Dec 30 07:28:55 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174764.304052] usb 8-1.8: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Dec 30 07:28:55 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174764.480053] usb 8-1.8: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
Dec 30 07:28:55 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174764.552052] usb 8-1.8: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Dec 30 07:28:55 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174764.728056] usb 8-1.8: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Dec 30 07:28:56 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174764.904056] usb 8-1.8: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
Dec 30 07:28:56 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174765.312044] usb 8-1.8: device not accepting address 12, error -32
Dec 30 07:28:56 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174765.384055] usb 8-1.8: new full-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
Dec 30 07:28:56 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174765.792062] usb 8-1.8: device not accepting address 13, error -32
Dec 30 07:28:56 thomas-linux-box kernel: [174765.792280] usb 8-1-port8: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I do not know how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- It means that there are problems with USB communication re-check USB Cable.
- Check power Port also the host could not provide enough electric power for USB Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Similar symptoms as a [Meizu phone user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772432/meizu-mx4-will-not-mount/772477#772477) except for the error code value.  Have you tried another USB stick or another USB device such as a backup drive?  Got a friend who could loan you a known working USB stick or another USB device?  Have you tried every USB port that you have?