# Meizu MX4 will not mount

Tags: usb, mount, ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

With the phone unlocked, I plug in the USB cable. Nothing happens. dmesg reports:

```
[190136.646920] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
[190136.647031] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190136.851142] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190137.055269] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 39, error -71
[190137.055295] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

lsusb is oblivious to the phone:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:5682 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So is adb devices:

```
List of devices attached
```

I have added the file ~/.android/adb_usb.ini with a single line containing the string '0x2a45'.

Help?

EDIT: I have now changed the BIOS options on my laptop, in order to have my USB ports work as USB2. Still cannot mount.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried your Meizu on another PC already?  Got a pal nearby who could help you?  Is the Meizu setup to act like a USB "disk drive".

The logs suggest that you are having USB communications problems.  I would try the following:

1. Try moving the USB cable to a different USB port connector.  Maybe, you are trying a front panel USB connector and the front panel is not actually wired to your motherboard inside the case (it happens).  How about trying a rear panel USB port?  In any case, try all of your USB ports.
2. If #1 fails, try a different USB cable which is known to work in all of the USB ports or it works on your pal's PC.
3. If both #1 and #2 fail, attach another phone to this Ubuntu system which is known to work on a different PC.  Does the 2nd phone work ok?  If it does then the Meizu has an issue with USB; you need to contact your Meizu support or the store where you bought it.
4. If the known good phone has the same issue as the Meizu, then the issue lies with your Ubuntu system USB support.  This should not have happened and I hope it doesn't when you test!

Good luck.

Comment: I have tried #1 and #2, to no avail. I found out that the phone works on my other laptop running 16.04 studio, so the phone is fine. This means that this is an issue with the ubuntu installation on my laptop. Any more hints?